# Add Style to each element in *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-style

I want to add a style to each element in my *ngFor

```
<div class=greenBox *ngFor="let item of items;" 
  [ngStyle]="{ 
    'top': item.Y,
    'left': item.X
  }">
    {{item.description}}
  </div>
```

when i do this as code above shows only the first elements style gets set:

```
<div class="greenBox ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="top: 0px; left: 0px;"> 0 </div>
<div class="greenBox ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"> 1 </div>
<div class="greenBox ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"> 2 </div>
<div class="greenBox ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"> 3 </div>
```

I expected to get a style attribute on each element.

Comment: It is getting applied. See the code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qar1sj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. Are you using `position: absolute` to style it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-style-to-each-element-in-ngfor?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

```
 <div class="greenBox" *ngFor="let item of items;" 
  [ngStyle]="{         
    'top.px': item.y,
    'left.px': item.x
  }">
    {{item.description}}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What does your `items` object look like?

I created this StackBlitz that mimics your code (I simply replaced `top` and `left` with `border` and `background-color` for a quick visual check): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rdb9tr

It works, so I'm guessing there may be an error in your `items` object...

Comment: my item has 3 properties,  a description a Y value and a X value
export interface item{

    description: string,
    X: number,
    Y: number,   
}
and when i edit the interpolation {{}} value it shows the correct values

Answer (score 1):

As per Angular doc:

> The styles are updated according to the value of the expression evaluation:
>
> - keys are style names with an optional `.<unit>` suffix (ie 'top.px', 'font-style.em'),
> - values are the values assigned to those properties (expressed in the given unit).

You can find complete reference [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

So your modified code should be:

```
<div class=greenBox *ngFor="let item of items;" 
    [ngStyle]="{'top.px': item.Y, 'left.px': item.X}">
        {{item.description}}
</div>
```